# Notepad++ add a character to the end of another character

Tags: notepad++

I'm trying to add `{1000}` to the end of every instance of `{LButton}` inside of

```
MouseMove, 1763, 265
Send, {LButton}
MouseMove, 1783, 329
Send, {LButton}
MouseMove, 1782, 340
...
```

In order to get

```
MouseMove, 1763, 265
Send, {LButton}{1000}
MouseMove, 1783, 329
Send, {LButton}{1000}
MouseMove, 1782, 340
...
```

I've googled through many threads, but haven't been able to solve this at all.

The biggest part of the problem I think here is finding an expression that doesn't conflict with the curly brackets.

Comment: What is the problem with just replacing {LButton}\r\n with {LButton}{1000}\r\n ??

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov Just tried it, but to no avail :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Example to replace with special character]

Suppose you are using regex. Use `'\'` character to escape `'{'` and `'}'` character should solve the problem. Following above cap screen should work.

Reference :[Character Escapes in Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-escapes-in-regular-expressions)